# Unable to make datatable responsive

Tags: lightning-datatable, responsive-design

I've followed the steps listed in [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.mobile_layout) article and added a grid to my layout, next I wrapped my datatable with `<lightning-layout>` and `<lightning-layout-item>` tags. but when I shrink the screen size the datatable stays the same.

I tried implementing [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/305647/responsive-layouts-in-lwc) solution but the datatable stays the same and not shrinking.

What am I missing?

```
<template >
        <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
          <div class="slds-col">
            <lightning-layout>
              <lightning-layout-item size="12">
                <lightning-datatable
                  key-field="id"
                  data={data}
                  columns={columns}>
                </lightning-datatable>                  
              </lightning-layout-item>
            </lightning-layout>
          </div>
        </div>
</template>
```

Comment: What's the issue (ex. where are you running into issues with responsiveness in particular?). If you just use `lightning-datatable` it does auto-size (although that doesn't mean it meets your need). See following [playground](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/h1uZ3Y8LiZuaYNmWTGMG) that compares your code to just using the standard component on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it's probably easiest to just add a single class to a datatable without any surrounding markup. Like this:

```
<template>
  <lightning-datatable key-field="id" data={data} columns={columns} class="slds-max-medium-table_stacked">
  </lightning-datatable>
</template>
```

Playground [here](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/03EncbRApLzD6U7g7rWe/src/app.html)

Comment: It seems the issue in my code is that the datatable is within a lightning tab

Comment: I manage to resolve everything by removing the two most outer divs:
  <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters"> AND 
   <div class="slds-var-m-around_xx-large">